# How can I create my class in different file?

Tags: c++, qt

can someone tell me how I can make a different file for My counter class?

this is my code but it is compiled by error.I should put my class in another file (.h).but I dont know how to do this..

My software is qt creator 5

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QObject>

class Counter : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    int m_value;
public:
    int value() const { return m_value; }
public slots:
    void setValue(int value);
signals:
    void valueChanged(int newValue);
};
void Counter::setValue(int value)
{
    if (value != m_value)
    {
        m_value = value;
        emit valueChanged(value);
    }
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    Counter d, b;
      QObject::connect(&d, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)),
                       &b, SLOT(setValue(int)));

     d.setValue(12);  // a.value() == 12, b.value() == 12

    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create Counter.h which is written as the followings:

```
#include <QObject>

class Counter : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT
    int m_value;
public:
    int value() const { return m_value; }
public slots:
    void setValue(int value);
signals:
    void valueChanged(int newValue);
}
```

Then put the following code into Couter.cpp

```
#include "Counter.h"

 void Counter::setValue(int value)
 {
    if (value != m_value)
    {
        m_value = value;
        emit valueChanged(value);
    }
 }
```

Now continue with your main.c

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "Couter.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    Counter d, b;
    QObject::connect(&d, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)),
                &b, SLOT(setValue(int)));

    d.setValue(12);  // a.value() == 12, b.value() == 12

    return a.exec();
}
```

I am not sure if you use qmake to build. If so you need to add the two file names, Couter.h and Counter.cpp into YourProjName.pro such as Counter.pro.

You should find more in Qt webpage for it.

Answer (score 0):

The class declaration should go in Counter.h.
The Counter::setValue method should go in Counter.C.
Both Counter.C and the file that contains main should include Counter.h.

Answer (score 0):

Put the class definition in a .h file:

Counter.h

```
#pragma once

#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QObject>

class Counter : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    int m_value;
public:
    int value() const { return m_value; }
public slots:
    void setValue(int value);
signals:
    void valueChanged(int newValue);
};
```

Put the definitions of the member functions in a .cpp file.

Counter.cpp:

```
#include "Counter.h"

void Counter::setValue(int value)
{
    if (value != m_value)
    {
        m_value = value;
        emit valueChanged(value);
    }
}
```

Put the `main` function in another .cpp file.

TestCounter.cpp:

```
#include "Counter.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    Counter d, b;
      QObject::connect(&d, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)),
                       &b, SLOT(setValue(int)));

     d.setValue(12);  // a.value() == 12, b.value() == 12

    return a.exec();
}
```

Since your class derived from `QObject`, you have to run the `moc` compiler, part of Qt distribution, to create another `.cpp` file. Compile all the .cpp files. Then, link the object files to create the executable.

Comment: it was so useful for me,big like ;)